# how to use yajra datatable in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, yajra-datatable

i want to use yajra datatable in my laravel 5.6 app i have install the yajra package using this (composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle) and include the js in my layout files when i run the app with php artisan serve it show this error (DataTables warning: table id=datatableclass - Invalid JSON response. ) any one can solve this thanks in advance.

config/app

```
'providers' => [

    ....

    Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    ....

    'Datatables' => 'Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables',

]
```

this is ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatableclass').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route('class.getclasses') }}',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'class_name', name: 'class_name'},

        ]
    });
});
```

this is my routes

```
Route::resource('/class','ClassController');
    Route::get('/class/get-classes', 'ClassController@getClass')->name('class.getclasses');
```

this is my controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\SchoolClassRequest;
use App\SchoolClass;
use Datatables;
     public function index()
        {
            return view('school_admin.entry.class');
        }
        public function getClass()
        {
            $school = auth()->user()->school()->first();
            $classes = SchoolClass::where('school_id', $school->id)->get();
            return DataTables::of($classes)->make(true);

        }
```

and this is my table in views

```
<table class="table" id="datatableclass">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="ID">Id</th>
          <th data-field="Class" data-sortable="true">Class Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


</table>
```

Comment: If the error tells you that the JSON response contains invalid stuff, can you share it?

Comment: the request has no response and show the error on alert box like DataTables warning: table id=datatableclass - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Why doesn't the response contain anything? That looks strange to me. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: i just want to return the response as json  but i think it return empty response but i do not know why it showing empty response

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? The `make` call looks strange to me - probably, you should try `toJson`, as documented?

Comment: Always show the response from your chrome debugger view. Maybe `class` is a protected keyword. See, if the getClass() function returns anything by using dd() in the right place